# Django Admin StackedInline

Tags: django

I have a stackedinline Django admin. This is used to add multiple products for a shop. However, when I click on 'Save and add another' it sometimes shows 'Entity too large', even when the files are below the allowed size, or sometimes it shows 'DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS' error. My question is, does Django stackedinline admin save each and every object each time we click on save? If no, then what could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

StackedInline is saved only when you click on main save.

It does save all through building the formsets and it does not use ajax requests for each of the rows ->  [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/inlines.js)

Also you can easily check this by inspecting and opening network tab